# Issue on Updating jQuery Timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple plugin to calculate date and time by this code:

```
<div id="timer"></div>

 <script>
 $.fn.timeCounter = function(time) {

    var target = new Date(time);
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = target.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    $("#timer").append( "<p>"+days+"</p>" );
    $("#timer").append( "<p>"+hours+"</p>" );
    $("#timer").append( "<p>"+minutes+"</p>" );
    $("#timer").append( "<p>"+seconds+"</p>" );
    var timer = setTimeout('timeCounter',1000);

};

$("#timer").timeCounter("june 16, 2014 00:01:00");
</script>
```

the code is working fine but I am having problem on displaying actual count down on numbers! can you please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: just for god sake let me know why did you vote this question down!?

Comment: `timeCounter` is not a function, you probably want `$.fn.timeCounter` also it takes an argument. Passing a string with the function name wouldn't do anything, the code in the string have to actually invoke the functuion.

Comment: Hi Musa thanks for reply, I updated the code as:  var timer = setTimeout('$.fn.timeCounter(time)',1000); but nothing changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following displays count down in seconds:

```
$.fn.timeCounter = function(time) {

    var target = new Date(time);
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = target.getTime() - now.getTime();

    // count down logic
    setTimeout(function cdtd(){

       if (timeDiff > 0){ 
       // reduce one seconds
       timeDiff-=1000;

       // change this to a more dedicated display per your requirements
       $('#timer').html(timeDiff/1000);

       // next one second, reference to cdtd
       setTimeout(cdtd,1000);}

    },1000);
}
```

See working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/danyu/X33kv/

Comment: Hi Danyu, thankd for code but please be aware that the cdtd() was a typo and I fix ed it in the code.now can you please let me know why you are using it? and how about other calculatins?

Comment: it is OK. I used it as a function name. in setTimeout, you can actually define a function with name. Also, check the working sample i just attached.

Comment: so do I have to repeat it for all hours, days seconds and minutes?

Comment: you don't have to. Get hours, minutes ... from timeDiff, which is milliseconds.

Comment: I changed sample to show the count down in format of hh,mm,ss.